# smarty get parts of text before and after comment

Tags: php, smarty

There is the text which containts `<!-- -->`

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris arcu sapien, ultrices quis ultricies vel, sodales pharetra massa. Donec iaculis hendrerit odio, quis facilisis odio aliquet non. <!-- -->Phasellus in euismod nunc, eget hendrerit tortor. In porttitor sem metus, ut porta turpis porta ac. Aenean sed semper mi. Fusce ac augue vel mi gravida bibendum eget a ex. Sed at auctor mauris, ut semper nibh. Sed in nisl nunc.`

How can I get the first part of text before comment (not including comment itself) and the second part of text after comment (not including comment itself too) in smarty?

In code below I get full text

```
{if $brand && $current_page_num==1}
  {$brand_descr="description_`$brand->url`"}
  {if $category->$brand_descr}
    {$category->$brand_descr}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use call php's reg_split inside smarty:

```
{$description="/(\s*<!--[^>]*>\s*)+/"|preg_split:$category->$brand_descr}

Before: {$description.0}
After: {$description.1}
```

I've also excluded the spaces before and after <-- -->, remove \s* from the regular expression if you don't want this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!